# Validation: implicit scalaz.Bind not found

Tags: validation, scala, scalaz

I have this implementation of scalaz Validation, it seems like that implicitly scalaz.Bind not in the scope, so for expression is not working.
Here is the code:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class User(name: String, knowScala: Boolean, age: Int)

object PublicValidationSpec extends BasicValidation {
  def validate(user: User): Validation[String, String] = {
    for {
      b <- checkAge(user)
      c <- checkName(user)
    } yield s"Congrats, ${c.name}"
  }
}

trait BasicValidation {
  def checkName(user: User): Validation[String, User] = {
    if(user.name == "") "must have a name".fail else user.success
  }

  def checkAge(user: User): Validation[String, User] = {
    if(user.age < 3) "must be a valid age".fail else user.success
  }
}
```

the exception is

```
Error:(14, 25) Implicit not found: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Bind, 
scalaz.Validation[String,scalaz.validation.User]]. Unable to unapply type 
`scalaz.Validation[String,scalaz.validation.User]` into a type constructor of 
kind `M[_]` that is classified by the type class `scalaz.Bind`. Check that the 
type class is defined by compiling `implicitly[scalaz.Bind[type constructor]]` and 
review the implicits in object Unapply, which only cover common type 'shapes.'
           b <- checkAge(user)

Did i miss some implicit imports here ?
                        ^
```

Comment: What version of scalaz?

Comment: "org.scalaz" % "scalaz-core_2.10" % "7.1.0-M5" and scala core library is 2.10.2

Comment: Updated my answer for 7.1.0-M5/6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Validation does not have a Bind defined for it.

In Scalaz 7.1.0-M5 (M6 too) `Validation.flatMap` is deprecated and in an attempt at subverting the warning, it looks like the precedence of `flatMap` is losing to `scalaz.syntax.bind._`, which is part of the `Scalaz._` import. See this commit https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/2727b2451eba2aa159f3fbb62bf92790ac99dc7a. Try adding `import scalaz.Validation.FlatMap._` or importing only the things you need, e.g.

```
import scalaz.Validation
import scalaz.syntax.validation._
```

I would recommend using something besides `Validation` though, as this will probably only cause you more problems in the future. See `scalaz.\/` below.

This does compile with scalaz 7.0.5. `Validation.flatMap` is defined in 7.0.6 so it should compile with that version too. I would not use this functionality (`Validation` in `for` comprehensions) in new code though.

The scalaz powers that be have gona back and forth on deprecating `Validation.flatMap` for some time now. `flatMap` is what allows it to work in `for` comprehensions. [`flatMap` *is* deprecated in the working branch though](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Validation.scala#L363-L373). There is a long background on this. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaz/Wnkdyhebo2w.

TLDR - Validation is not a monad. Any possible implementation of `Validation.flatMap` will not match behavior of the `Apply` defined for `Validation`.

Use `scalaz.\/` (a.k.a. disjunction) if you want to use something in `for` comprehensions. If you need to accumulate errors, the reason to use `Validation` over `\/`, convert to `Validation` and then back to `\/`.

Comment: @CareyGregory was working on a more complete answer, but wanted to reply with the short version first. I did leave a request for the particular version he was using though. It also answered his question which was, "Did i miss some implicit imports here ?"

Comment: What's the rush? Doing that got your answer flagged for deletion since it was initially just the first sentence.

Comment: @CareyGregory As I stated, it answered the question, which was, "Did i miss some implicit imports here ?" You could have provided a better answer also.

Comment: grrr, I accidentally +1'ed you comment instead of flagging it.

Comment: Why on earth would you flag my comment? Do you somehow find it to be unconstructive or offensive? I was simply attempting to explain that someone flagged your answer as low quality because it was just a single sentence. So it came up in my review queue and I agreed and recommended deletion. The mod who reviews it will see that you subsequently added a complete answer and therefore ignore my recommendation. I don't see the problem.

Comment: I wanted to flag it because it was incorrect. I did provide an answer to the question. It may have been a short answer, but it was an answer. Was it better to have my original answer or was it better to have no answer?

Comment: It would have been better to wait until your answer was complete before posting it. There are no prizes awarded for being first and there is no time limit.